# Rails 3.2 and yui compressor

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, sprockets

The [Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#css-compression) on the asset pipeline says you can use the yui-compressor on CSS with:

```
config.assets.css_compressor = :yui
```

However, I see no sign that it is actually using it.  For one, thing, it makes no difference whether or not I have the yui-compressor gem installed or not.  For another, compressed output is the same whether I have that line or not.

I put a little debug line into `actionpack-3.2.3/lib/sprockets/compressors.rb` in the `registered_css_compressor` method, and this is the result when the css is compiled: `#<Sass::Rails::CssCompressor:0x007fdef9f9fee0>`

So it appears that the config line is not being honored.   Has anyone actually used this option?

**Update**

Looking in [sass-rails](https://github.com/rails/sass-rails/blob/3-2-stable/lib/sass/rails/railtie.rb) shows that the selection is overridden:

```
if app.config.assets.compress
    app.config.sass.style = :compressed
    app.config.assets.css_compressor = CssCompressor.new
end
```

If I comment that out, then it actually attempts to start the yui compressor... I'm still checking the output to see if it is correct.

Comment: Are you trying this in your production or development environment? Rails does not compress assets by default in development.

Comment: I set my development config to compress.   It compresses, but not with the yui lib.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It truly is a bug in rails. I created a patch and [pull request](https://github.com/rails/sass-rails/pull/105) to fix it.